# Laravel Cashier Stripe error default_payment_method

Tags: laravel-10, laravel-cashier

I need to make a user subscription Stripe. I use the payment page:

```
public function paymentForm()
{
    $id = \request()->get('id');

    $plan = Plan::find(1);
    $intent = auth()->user()->createSetupIntent();

    return view("user.subscription", compact("plan", "intent", "id"));
}

// Post action
public function subscription(Request $request)
{
    $plan = Plan::where('slug', 'standard')->first();

    $subscription = $request->user()
        ->newSubscription($plan->slug, $plan->stripe_plan)
        ->create($request->paymentMethod);

    $subscription->ends_at = Carbon::now()->addDays(6);
    $subscription->save();

    return redirect()->to('user/payment');
}
```

After sending the form, I get the following error: Attempt to read property "default_payment_method" on null.

```
dd($request->paymentMethod); //pm_1OWfTrIDQRzGQKp4IDkRK2Gi
```

JS code:

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
<script>
    const stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}')
    const elements = stripe.elements()
    const cardElement = elements.create('card');
    cardElement.mount('#card-element')

    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form')
    const cardBtn = document.getElementById('card-button')
    const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name')

    form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        cardBtn.disabled = true
        const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.confirmCardSetup(

            cardBtn.dataset.secret, {
                payment_method: {
                    card: cardElement,
                    billing_details: {
                        name: cardHolderName.value
                    }
                }
            }
        )

        if(error) {
            cardBtn.disable = false
        } else {
            let token = document.createElement('input')
            token.setAttribute('type', 'hidden')
            token.setAttribute('name', 'paymentMethod')
            token.setAttribute('value', setupIntent.payment_method)
            form.appendChild(token)
            form.submit();
        }
    })
</script>
```

The data token is generated on the client side, but for some reason an error occurs.

[image]

Comment: What is the `->create` call coming from? Is that null in this case? If you place a breakpoint and inspect other variables involved in that call, does your debugger indicate that any of them are null? Alternatively, you can break that call out in to multiple steps and check what the variables are at each step.

Answer (score 0):

t worked.It was necessary to clear the fields(stripe_id, pm_type,pm_last_four) in the user table